# Find the greatest date when multiple threads provide it to the same function

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Let's say I have this function:

```
class Example
{
    private DateTime m_date;
    private string m_id;

    public void Max(DateTime date, string id)
    {
        if (date > m_date)
        {
            m_date = date;
            m_id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Multiple threads hold the same instance of `Example`, and each is calling the `Max()` function.

I want to have the correct date and id after all the calls (as if it was called sequentially).

One option is to use a lock obviously, but I'd be glad to avoid that here (using Interlocked or something similar).

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to make it truely thread safe without using a lock, since you have 3 lines of code and only if those are locked at the same time your code works, even with @MickyD 's shared code you only made 2 lines thread safe, comparing and setting `m_date` but setting the `m_id` will not be thread safe and it will most likely give an unexpected result, you would need a CompareExchange which would need to change 2 variables based on one condition.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a `lock`? A performance issue? I think you need to show us the rest of your code so that we can actually provide valuable help.